# Bash script for running python virtual environment does not execute

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I am trying to wrap the following call into a script, which runs my Python virtual environment:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas/bin$ source /home/lucas/Dropbox/projects/competitive-programming/kaggle/venv/ipython-notebook/bin/activate                                
(ipython-notebook) [lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas/bin$ deactivate
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas/bin$
```

So, I created and ran the following bash script:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas/bin$ cat venv_python3.sh 
#!/bin/bash
#  /usr/bin/env bash
echo "starting python3 venv"
source /home/lucas/Dropbox/projects/competitiveprogramming/kaggle/venv/ipythonnotebook/bin/activate
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas/bin$ venv_python3.sh 
starting python3 venv                                                                            
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas/bin$
```

As you can see, it executes the `echo` call, but does not start my virtual environment. Am I missing something?

I've looked over several tutorials, but cannot find what is missing. Also, my `/home/lucas/bin/`, the location of my script, is in my `$PATH`.

Here are the file's permissions:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas/bin$ ls -la
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  3 lucas lucas 4096 Jun 28 23:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 79 lucas lucas 4096 Jun 28 23:13 ..
-rwxrw-r--  1 lucas lucas  164 Jun 28 23:13 venv_python3.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

At the top of the `activate` script it says you have to source it and that you cannot run it directly. What it does, is changing some things in the session of `bash` into which the file is sourced.

In your case that `bash` is the `bash` that is invoked by running the `venv_python3.sh` script, **not** the `bash` you are typing into interactively.

What you could do is make a bash function (or an alias) that does the sourcing for you, then the 'sourcing' would happen to your interactive `bash`.

However I recommend you look at [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which makes working with multiple virtualenvs much more easy and might solve the 'problem' for which you created this script in the first place.